# Calling Custom Method Inside SKSpriteNode Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a custom SKSpriteNode object and want to call a custom method inside it "Set Defaults".

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Platform : SKSpriteNode

- (instancetype)initWithDynamicPlatform;
- (void)setDefaults;

@end
```

And in the .m file

```
#import "Platform.h"

@implementation Platform

- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
if (self == [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
    NSLog(@"Initiated Platform");
}
return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithDynamicPlatform {

if (self == [super initWithImageNamed:@"Platform2"]) {
    NSLog(@"Initiated Platform");
}

[self setDefaults];

return self;
}

- (void)setDefaults {

/**
 * Set the name
 */

self.name = @"Platform";

/**
 * Set the effect of gravity on the platform
 */

self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


 }

 @end
```

The problem is that from the SKScene file I cannot access the custom method.

```
- (void)loadDynamicPlatform {

SKSpriteNode *spritePlatform = [[Platform alloc] initWithDynamicPlatform];    

[spritePlatform setDefaults];

[self addChild:spritePlatform];
[self movePlatform:spritePlatform];

}
```

I get the error message

> "/Users/****/Desktop/Apps/****/****/GameScene.m:142:21:
>   No visible @interface for 'SKSpriteNode' declares the selector
>   'setDefaults'"

Any idea why I can not access this. I am sure I was setting it up correctly.

Comment: Do you `#import "Platform.h"` in  `GameScene.m`?

Comment: Yeah thats there in the GameScene.m file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare a 'Platform' variable or cast the 'SKSpriteNode' to 'Platform':

```
Platform *spritePlatform = [[Platform alloc] initWithDynamicPlatform];    

[spritePlatform setDefaults];
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for that. I have changed the code now and it works.

Comment: That's great. Happy to help